Can't figure out how to get all the functionality of google api reviews
There are docs online that show that I should be able to access all of my businesses google reviews through the api, select specific reviews, reply to reviews, and delete replies all through the places API. It looks like this has all been deprecated as of the of 2023. Is there still a way to implement this so I can see and reply to my reviews through my web application?
Here's my resource for what I want to be able to do.
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data
If this is still possible, could I get an explanation on what is needed to make this work?
I've used numerous tutorials on youtube, stackoverflow, and the google api documentation, but none of these options have been able to generate the result I want. I'm worried that google did indeed deprecate this service.

You're mentioning about using Places API to do these things, but the link you provided is from google business profile API. And looking into your issue, Google Business Profile is what you should use instead of the Places API. The documentation you linked shows the methods on how to use the API and I believe that should suffice if you know enough about APIs.
